# How to bypass node level in GoJS?

Tags: charts, gojs

I'm trying to create tree chart like this in GoJS : 
[chart sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A1dX.jpg)

How to bypass child 1 level so child 3 will be at equal position or level as child 2 ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have posted an answer on the GoJS forum: http://forum.nwoods.com/t/how-to-bypass-node-level-in-gojs/6819

This is a more general solution where you want to specify the level or layer of each node of a tree, with certain restrictions, as a property of the model node data objects.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your requirements are, you might merely want to position the leaf nodes of the tree to all be in the same bottom layer.

If that is the case, you could use the custom TreeLayout defined in the Parse Tree sample, http://gojs.net/latest/samples/parseTree.html.